# Finite cyclic subgroups of the homeomorphisms of the real numbers

Tags: general-topology, group-theory, continuity, real-numbers

This inquiry was inspired by this post: [The automorphism group of the real line with standard topology](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763964/the-automorphism-group-of-the-real-line-with-standard-topology).

While trying to come up with some interesting examples, I attempted to figure out the finite cyclic subgroups of the homeomorphisms of the reals with their Euclidean topology (under composition). I believe them to be $\{1_\Bbb R\}$ and $\langle(x\mapsto -x)\rangle$ just from intuition, but I haven't been able to show this completely. Here's what I have done:

Suppose $f$ is homeomorphism of $\Bbb R$ with $f^{[n]}=1_\Bbb R$ for some $n$. We have that $f$ is either (strictly) increasing or decreasing. Suppose $f$ is strictly increasing. Let $x\in\Bbb R$. Either $x\leq f(x)$ or $f(x)\leq x$. In the first case, induction shows that $x\leq f(x)\leq f^{[2]}(x)\leq\cdots\leq f^{[n]}(x)=x$ and thus $f(x)=x$. In the latter case, induction shows that $x=f^{[n]}(x)\leq\cdots\leq f^{[2]}(x)\leq f(x)\leq x$ and we have again that $f(x)=x$. Since $x$ was arbitrary, we have that $f=1_\Bbb R$.

Now we only have to deal with a strictly decreasing homeomorphism, but my attempts have been fruitless. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The reflection of the real line $R_a : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ defined by $R_a(x) = 2a - x$ generates a group of order two, so there are certainly more examples than $1_{\mathbb R}$ and $x \mapsto -x$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $f$ is strictly decreasing, then if $x < y$, $f(x) > f(y)$, and so $f(f(x)) < f(f(y))$. Hence $f^{[2]}$ is strictly increasing, and is a homeomorphism, which means by your previous reasoning the order of $f$ must be $1$ or $2$.

However, it's not true that every involutive (order 2) homeomorphism of $\mathbb{R}$ is $x \mapsto -x$. In fact, if $f:\mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ and $Z$ is a cyclic subgroup, then $f^{-1}Zf$ is also a cyclic subgroup, and in your case if $i$ is an involution $f^{-1}if$ is another involution. Concretely, $x \mapsto f^{-1}(-f(x))$ is an order 2 homeomorphism of the real line. Examples are $x \mapsto a - x$ or $x \mapsto (a - x^3)^{1/3}$

So the question is: Are all involutions conjugate to $x \mapsto -x$? I'm not sure now, but I think the answer is yes.

Comment: yes this is true: indeed is $f$ is a nontrivial involution, then $f$ is increasing and has a unique fixed point $x_0$. Define an increasing self-homeo $u$ of the reals as follows: on $[0,\infty[$ it's a homeo onto $[x_0,\infty[$, and on $]-\infty,0]$, it maps $t\le 0$ to $f(u(-t))$. Then $f=usu^{-1}$, where $s(x)=-x$.