# A Jordan Curve Symmetric About the Origin Does Not Pass Through Origin

Tags: general-topology, geometry, curves

I've been thinking about this statement for a while, and I think it's true, but I'm not sure of how to prove it. The statement is

> A Jordan curve $J$ that is symmetric about the origin $p$ does not pass through $p$.

I think one should be able to argue by contradiction that if $J$ passes through the origin, then $J$ has a self-intersection, which contradicts the fact $J$ is a Jordan curve, but I'm having trouble with the details.

Comment: How does one formalize "symmetric about the origin" for a Jordan curve? If curve goes through $(x,y)$ then also goes through $(-x,-y)$?

Comment: @coffeemath "Symmetric about the origin" means the curve is unchanged when reflected across both the x-axis and y-axis, which is exactly what you have described.

Comment: It seems like you should be able to show that the interior is symmetric about the origin, so it contains some disk about the origin.

Comment: Hint: Show first that a homeomorphism if order 2 of the real line has a fixed point. Then argue that Jordan curve minus a point is homeomorphic to ...

Comment: @MoisheKohan Would you expand on this a bit, please? I don't see it.  To begin with, does "order $2$" mean $\phi\circ\phi = id?$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK: Suppose that $J\subset R^n$ is a Jordan curve invariant under the antipodal map $\phi: x\mapsto -x$ and $0\in J$. Then $\phi$ restricts to an involution $\tau$ on $J-\{0\}\cong {\mathbb R}$: $\tau\circ \tau=id$.  Since $\phi$ has only one  fixed point, $\tau$ has no fixed points. Now, contradiction comes from the following lemma

**Lemma.** Let $f: {\mathbb R}\to {\mathbb R}$ be a homeomorphism of finite order $k$, i.e. $f^k=id$. Then $f$ has at least one fixed point.

I will leave you a proof as an exercise, compare [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/775251/finite-cyclic-subgroups-of-the-homeomorphisms-of-the-real-numbers).

Comment: Very slick! This makes sense. Thank you.