# Is there any way to define a group action of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ on $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-topology, group-actions, fundamental-groups

I recently read that defining the action of $\mathbb{Z}$ on $\mathbb{R}$ by translation, i.e. $x \mapsto x+n$ for $x\in \mathbb{R}, n\in \mathbb{Z}$, gives that $\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z}\cong S^1$, and this gives that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}/\mathbb{Z})\cong \mathbb{Z}$. I was wondering if there is any way to define a group action on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}/(\mathbb{Z}/n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$.

EDIT: sorry if the question was confusing. I guess my main question is if there is any way to define a group action of $\mathbb{Z}/n$ on $\mathbb{R}$ in general. As a second question, would such an action satisfy $\pi_1(\mathbb{R}/(\mathbb{Z}/n)) \cong \mathbb{Z}/n$ where the quotient map $q:\mathbb{R}\to \mathbb{R}/(\mathbb{Z}/n)$ is a covering (in this case I believe the answer that Kenta S gave disproves this claim).

Comment: The title and body question don't match which is perhaps causing confusion; it would be good to clarify if you intend for this action to be such that the quotient map is a covering map.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider an action of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb R$. I'll assume that this is an action in the topological category, i.e. an action by homeomorphisms, which is the most general situation that seems relevant to the tags of this post.

I'll lay out a proof that an action of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ on $\mathbb R$ either is trivial and hence its quotient is just $\mathbb R$, or the action factors through a reflection action of $\mathbb Z/2\mathbb Z$ and so its quotient is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$.

Pick a generator of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ and let $\alpha : \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ denote the action of that generator.

By an argument applying the intermediate value theorem, one can prove that if $\alpha$ has no fixed points then it is either strictly increasing or strictly decreasing, implying that $\alpha$ has infinite order. [Side note: it follows furthermore that $\alpha$ is topologically conjugate to a translation homeomorphism $x \mapsto x+1$].

But $\alpha$ was assumed to have finite order, and so we obtain a contradiction.

We conclude that the set $F \subset \mathbb R$ of fixed ponts of $\alpha$ is nonempty, and it is a closed subset of $\mathbb R$.

Note that $\alpha$ acts on $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$, either fixing them both  or transposing them, and we'll consider two separate cases.

**Case 1:** $\alpha$ fixes both $-\infty$ and $+\infty$. In this case we'll prove that $F=\mathbb R$, hence $\alpha$ is the identity map, hence the action is trivial.

For the proof, assuming that $F \ne \mathbb R$, consider a component $J$ of $\mathbb R - F$, which is an open interval with endpoints in the set $F \cup \{-\infty,+\infty\}$. The endpoints of $J$ are fixed by $\alpha$, and it follows that $\alpha(J)=J$. But $J$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$, hence the restriction $\alpha \mid J$ has a fixed point not in the set $F$, which is a contradiction.

Note in this case that the quotient $\mathbb R / (\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z)$ is just $\mathbb R$, whose fundamental group is trivial.

**Case 2:** $\alpha$ transposes $\{-\infty,+\infty\}$. It follows that $F$ is bounded, hence compact, and hence has a max and a min. Furthermore, $\alpha$ takes $\min(F)$ to $\max(F)$ and $\max(F)$ to $\min(F)$. But both $\min(F)$ and $\max(F)$ are fixed by $\alpha$, hence $\min(F) = \max(F)$ and so $F$ is a single point.

Applying Case 1 to $\alpha^2 = \alpha \circ \alpha$, it follows that $\alpha^2$ is the identity map. Hence $n$ is even and the action of $\mathbb Z / n \mathbb Z$ factors through an action of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ whose fixed point set is the one-point set $F$. In this case the quotient is homeomorphic to $[0,\infty)$ whose fundamental group is trivial.

[Side note: There are indeed actions like this, because $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ can act as a reflection map $x \mapsto -x$ on $\mathbb R$. With just a bit more work, one can prove that every action of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$ is topologically conjugate to a reflection action. Hence if $\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z$ acts nontrivially on $\mathbb R$ then $n$ is even, and the action is topologically conjugate to an action that factors through a reflection action of $\mathbb Z / 2 \mathbb Z$.]

Comment: For the last claim about the classification of actions of $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$, [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/775251/258909) is relevant. See also Section 9.4 of [this page](http://www.map.mpim-bonn.mpg.de/1-manifolds) about manifolds of dimension 1.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose there is such an action. Then $\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z/n)$ would again be a connected non-compact $1$-manifold. It must thus be diffeomorphic to $\mathbb R$. We thus obtain a $n$-fold cover $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$. But $\mathbb R$ has trivial fundamental group, so it does not admit a non-trivial covering.

Comment: $\mathbb{Z}/2$ acts on $\mathbb{R}$ via $x \mapsto -x$. The quotient is not diffeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}$ and the quotient map is not a covering map.

Comment: I interpreted the question to be asking $\pi_1(\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z/n))\simeq\mathbb Z/n$ via the covering map $\mathbb R\to\mathbb R/(\mathbb Z/n)$.

Comment: I don't understand why this answer was downvoted; as far as I can tell it correctly addresses the OP's question as stated (in the body).