# How to describe all homeomorphisms on $l^2$

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, lp-spaces, morphism

I know homeomorphisms are something like transformations of a space. But I am struggling to make some "system" of all homeomorphisms of given space (say $l^2$) and whether we can describe them all somehow.

How do the homeomorphisms on $l^2$ look like? Can they be classified or categorized somehow? Can we define a category of homeomorphisms on $l^2$? (By $l^2$, I mean the Hilbert space of all square summable sequences.)

Since $l^2$ is of similar nature to $\mathbb{R}^2$, do also the homeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $l^2$ have something in common? (E.g. can we describe homeomorphisms on $l^2$ using homeomorphisms on $\mathbb{R}^2$?

Comment: Why do you day $l^2$ is of similar nature to $\mathbb R^2$ ?

Comment: @Yorch Maybe I should say $\mathbb{R}^n$ generally? Since $l^p$ spaces have elements, which are like vectors, but with infinite number of components (vector corresponds to sequence of components here), so I suppose it behaves similarly. But please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: the space of homeomorphisms of $\ell^2$ is huge; I doubt that there exists a simple description

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich I didnt expected anything simple, but more like if the homeomorphisms can be categorized somehow, according to properties they have in common etc.
Since if we only took autohomeomorphisms, they would form a group naturally, so I hoped for some structure for all homeomorphisms too.

Comment: There are so many options for stuff you can do, it is most likely an incredibly rich group with a ton of different subgroups. See this post where they discuss the same group but for the much more restrictive topology $\mathbb R$. https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/763964/the-automorphism-group-of-the-real-line-with-standard-topology

Comment: $\ell^2$ is homeomorphic to any separable completely metrisable locally convex topological vector space of infinite dimensions. So to $\ell^p$ or $\Bbb R^{\Bbb N}$ as well, e.g. Classifying automorphisms is a hopeless problem, from infinite-dimensional topology results we know there are far too many of them.